# c++: can vector<Base> contain objects of type Derived?

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism, object-slicing

The title pretty much says it all. Basically, is it legal to do this:

```
class Base {
    //stuff
}

class Derived: public Base {
    //more stuff
}

vector<Base> foo;
Derived bar;
foo.push_back(bar);
```

Based on other posts I've seen, the following is okay, but I don't want to use pointers in this case because it's harder to make it thread safe.

```
vector<Base*> foo;
Derived* bar = new Derived;
foo.push_back(bar);
```

Comment: Why is thread-safety in any way relevant here? Did you mean exception-safety perhaps? If so, yes, `push_back` could throw an exception, leaving out a dangling pointer. You can use smart pointers to handle that.

Comment: @DanielKO I'm using an STL container as a buffer between a producer and consumer thread. I don't want to fill the container with pointers because even though I've protected the container itself with a mutex, once any thread has a pointer to some other data, that data is not protected.

Comment: That itself is not a thread-safety problem. Even without pointers one can also mess around with the elements in a thread-unsafe way. All you have to do is to define the proper semantics so the contents (stored as pointers or directly) are not modified without the proper concurrency consistency mechanisms. In particular, if you are afraid a user of the class might store a pointer to the element without "permission", what makes you think he won't take a pointer or a reference in the same way?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, the `Derived` objects will be [*sliced*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c): all additional members will be discarded.

Instead of raw pointers, use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base> >`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore "can vector<Base> contain objects of type Derived?" -> No, they will be sliced, so they'll be just `Base` objects. It isn't illegal, but it's not true either.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore "No, vector<Base> can't contain objects of type Derived".  Because once they're sliced they aren't `Derived` any more.

Comment: @Heisenbug the `Base` that ends up in the vector is copy constructed from the `Derived` object being pushed. If a copy construction generates a leak, then you've got a problem in your code :D.

Comment: @Heisenbug - No, there is no leak. The vector stores a copy of the object. Being a `vector<Base>`, it just copies the Base part.

Comment: @ecatmur Can you explain how smart pointers will serve the purpose? Won't object slicing still happen?

Comment: @gargankit the templated converting constructor of `unique_ptr<Base>` transfers ownership of the contained pointer, so the `Derived` object is not sliced.

Answer (score 4):

It's *legal* but suffers from object slicing. Basically, you'll have a vector of `Base` objects. No polymorphism, type info will be lost for derived objects... It's as if you'd just be adding `Base` objects to the vector.

You can use smart pointers instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
vector<Base> foo;
Derived bar;
foo.push_back(bar);
```

This is equal to pushing Base object, because `push_back` is declared like this:

```
void push_back ( const T& x );
```

So, compiler will do implicit downgrading conversion and do copy into vector memory pool.
No, it is not possible to contain `Derived` inside `vector<Base>`. They will be `Base`.

If you add some virtual function to `Base` then override it in `Derived`, create `Derived` object, push it into `vector<Base>` and then call it from vector's new object, you will see that `Base` implementation is called