# C++ Vector of Derived Class Objects (without pointer) possible?

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism

I have a base class A and some classes B, C, ... which inherits from A.
I would like to know if I am obliged to use polymorphism to store some derived class objects in a vector for example.

The standard way is:

```
std::vector<A*> myVector;
A* obj1 = new B;
A* obj2 = new C;
myVector.push_back(obj1);
myVector.push_back(obj2);
```

However, if I don't need to use polymorphism can I do?

```
std::vector<A> myVector;
B obj1;
C obj2;
myVector.push_back(obj1);
myVector.push_back(obj2);
```

Comment: Your "standard way" is awful. It should be `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>>`. And yes, it requires a virtual destructor.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/274626/596781

Comment: You can also implement a type which internally holds a pointer to a polymorphic implementation, and give it value semantics.

Comment: Thank you Kerrek. Why is it awful?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889178/c-can-vectorbase-contain-objects-of-type-derived

Comment: Thank you Retired Ninja, didn't find that one when I posted !

Comment: Using naked pointers in STL containers leads to memory leaks, primarily, if you aren't careful. You have to explicitly delete them. And if you are using STL calls like `erase` or `remove` then it becomes quite twisted to guarantee safe behavior.

Comment: Thank you DumbCoder. I am not familiar with the STL, I mainly use the QTL :)